# Why does applying of JSON.stringify takes so much memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Here is an example of NodeJS code:

```
function toMB (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

console.log('Node memory usage:', toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

var veryLongString = Array(10000000).join('qweqweqweqweqweqweq');

console.log('Node memory usage after string creation:',  toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
console.log('String memory length: ', toMB(Buffer.byteLength(veryLongString)) + ' MB');

JSON.stringify({'str': veryLongString});

console.log('Node memory usage after "JSON.stringify" apply:',  toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
```

I have got the following results:

```
Node memory usage: 2.01 MB
Node memory usage after string creation: 183.25 MB
String memory length:  181.20 MB
Node memory usage after "JSON.stringify" apply: 545.37 MB
```

Why does memory usage grew in 3 times(!!!) after JSON.stringify applying?

Code without using "veryLongString":

```
function toMB (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

console.log('Node memory usage:', toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

JSON.stringify({'str': Array(10000000).join('qweqweqweqweqweqweq')});

console.log('Node memory usage after "JSON.stringify" apply:',  toMB(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
```

have the same result:

```
Node memory usage: 2.00 MB
Node memory usage after "JSON.stringify" apply: 545.36 MB
```

Comment: That should be an aswer @Digigizmo, not a comment :)

Answer (score -1):

Line:

```
JSON.stringify({'str': Array(10000000).join('qweqweqweqweqweqweq')});
```

create new string object which contains json. Something like this:

```
{"str":"qweqweqweqweqweqweq.........."}
```

and now we have two strings :)